# How to transfer fee to marketplace owner's bank account

Tags: balanced-payments

I am using a test marketplace and I want to implement fee deduction. But I do not know the URI of the marketplace owner's bank account. Where can I get this URI? Or do I have to construct it myself from the bank account id in the Dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the bank account associated with the `owner_account` or `owner_customer` object.

If you're using [balanced-ruby](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby) you could use

```
Balanced::Marketplace.mine.owner_customer.destination
```

or if you're using Accounts instead of Customers

```
Balanced::Marketplace.mine.owner_account.bank_accounts.all(:first)
```